# Using jQuery.each() to assign errors to form fields

Tags: jquery

I have these elements:

```
<div class="qtip-error">...</div>
<div class="qtip-error">...</div>
<div class="qtip-error">...</div>
```

and

```
<span class="validation-error">...</span>
<span class="validation-error">...</span>
<span class="validation-error">...</span>
```

What is the best way to assign each span to the corresponding div based on the index? I've been looking at somehow implementing `.each()` but I'm not sure how to make it work right. If there is a better approach, I am open to suggestions, but please, no plugins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var qtips = $('.qtip-error');
$('.validation-error').each(function (i) {
   qtips.eq(i).after(this);
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zR9bL/.

Instead of `after(this)` you can use `append(this)` if you want the `<span>` to be within the `<div>`.